# Creating a grouped and stacked bar chart with nvd3

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am looking to create a chart with nvd3 that looks like the one below:[image: chart in Excel]

In this chart, it is essentially a nested x-axis where I have a price ranges, and I am tracking the prices from different stores (and the categories within each store) in those ranges.  I know I can do a simple chart with just one store and then I wouldn't need the nested x-axis, but I need to be able to do the side-by-side comparison as well.

Looking through the examples and documentation, it appears that nvd3 does not support this advanced chart type.  I have used nvd3 to create plenty of simple bar charts, but this is my first attempt at a more advanced chart.  If nvd3 does not support this, is there a library outside of d3 itself that you can recommend.  I have looked at dimple.js, but it does not look like that it is being actively supported as the last commit was in 2016.

Comment: I haven't used Chart.js myself, but it looks like it should be able to do it. Example: https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/stacked-group.html - documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html

Comment: Thank you.  That example is definitely what I am looking for.  Hopefully, I can manipulate the labels and things a bit more, but this definitely warrants a deeper look.  Thanks again.